# Overrride AddedControl method

Tags: asp.net, controls, overriding

I would like to override the `AddedControl` method for each control inside my ASP.NET page, so that it gets executed for all labels, checkboxes, linkbuttons inside my page.

```
protected override void AddedControl(Control control, int index)
{
    base.AddedControl(control, index);
    ParseControls(control); // do stuff in here
}
```

My problem is that if I add this method in the master page, it gets called only for controls with types:

- System.Web.UI.LiteralControl
- System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead
- System.Web.UI.LiteralControl
- System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm
- System.Web.UI.ResourceBasedLiteralControl

Where should I place it so that it gets fired for each ASP.NET control?

Comment: Maybe a silly question but... Are there controls other than those types on the master page itself?  I would think most of the other controls are on other pages, which would also need to override this method, no?

Comment: I also considered this and tried adding the code above to each page inside the project, but still, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps adding controls inside a container (like a Panel), and you see only the container? In that case you will not see the AddedControl method called for controls inside that container, because they are Added to the container, not to the page.

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I realized I was not calling this function recursively for each control and its children. Now that I do, I can see only the tabpanels inside the tabcontainer of the (AJAX) panel. Is there a way I see the controls inside the container, too? Thank you!

Comment: The container would have to override AddedControl by itself. 
What are you trying to do in the end, in ParseControl? Maybe there's another approach to this?

Comment: I need to get all the controls inside the container to change their InnerHTML text according to user settings.

Comment: You could iterate through all controls on Page Load, perhaps? By that time all controls are present and you can "push" them into your procedure.